# Packages have unmet dependencies dot.net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

Unable install .net core 1.0.4 version on Ubuntu 16.04 using

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.4
```

System generates the following error.

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     dotnet-dev-1.0.4 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 is to be installed
                        Depends: dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.2 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried the following based on the comments that I have seen in stackoverflow for unmet dependencies. Nothing worked.

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.4
```

Any recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the following command

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://aptmo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 417A0893

sudo apt-get update
```

taken from [Get Started with .NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) note that you need the 16.04 part